# WUBI installation of Kubuntu 12.04.1 LTS hangs at Splash Screen

Tags: kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

System: Toshiba Satellite laptop: specs: Intel Pentium Dual Core 1.7 GHz, mobile Intel 965 GPU , 2 GB RAM - with Windows Vista Home Premium. (trying to dual-boot this and Kubuntu)

Installed Kubuntu using WUBI (in the same folder), rebooted, then selected Kubuntu.
A message says: `Completing Ubuntu installation in 3...2...1`

After the Kubuntu splash screen starts with the dots changing colour (black to white). When they all turn black, the whole screen hangs. I cant even get to the login screen yet. However, when using demo mode, everything is fine. So what is going on?